# How can I update client side data when MongoDb field is updated for a document

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

On the client side, a user clicks a button which increments a point to their field in their MongoDB document.

The backend returns the updated document.

I wish to know the best way to update the client side data with the updated data.

Backend Code

```
export const addPoint = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const updatedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
        {_id : req.params.id },
        {$inc: { housePoints: 1 }},
        {new : true}
      );
      res.status(200).json(updatedUser);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  };
```

Client Code

```
const handleClick = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const userId = e.target.id;
    const res = await axios.put(`/api/teacher/find/${userId}/add`)
    console.log(res.data)
  };
```

Here is an image of the interface to add context.

[image: A user clicks the div to add a housepoint]

The firebase equivalent is to have a live database. I am unsure whether the same is possible with MongoDB, or whether I would be better off updating the data from a global dataContext.

Thank you

Comment: The response should have the updated data and update the field by setting the state ...

Comment: The data that is coming in the response is suppose to be a globally accessed data or only the component in which the api call is being made is required to access it?

Comment: @ShubhamWaje, if I understand your question, the data is changed for one student on a single page which displays multiple students. This data is globally accessible to the individual that is logged in.

Comment: So on update you want to change data on the card for the student's data which got edited?

Comment: @ShubhamWaje, this is correct.

Comment: Can you share the code of your whole component where this logic is being handled?

Comment: @ShubhamWaje, this is my question. I haven't attempted the logic yet. I am not surre what is best. Do I look into 'watching' the database to listen for changes?

Comment: Ok so I think you should create a state which has initial value as an empty array `[]` then when you are getting all the students set that response data from backend to the state. Then when you are editing you can directly update the same state for a particular object with `id ===userId` in the function where you are doing the `PUT` request.